# Updating entity with another entity in C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a bunch of entities that need to be updated to match entities of the same class in a different database. For example:

```
Database1 TableA:
Id| User       | FirstName| LastName
1 | Geekguy123 | Fred     | Smith

Database2 TableA:
Id| User       | FirstName| LastName
34| Geekguy123 | Frederick| Smith
```

How can I update database1 for Geekguy123 so the new FirstName is Frederick? The ids are different but the User is unique.

To be clear, there are dozens of properties on the entity, which I don't want to update manually. Maybe SQL would be easier?

Comment: Those are tables, not databases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just query in database 1 for the record you want. Get its FirstName property and then query the record in database 2 and then update firstname field with the one you got from database 1. And then submit your change.

```
Db1Context c1 = new Db1Context();
var userToUpdateWith = c1.Users.Single(u => u.User == "Geekguy123")

Db2Context c2 = new Db2Context();
var userToUpdate = c2.Users.Single(u => u.User == "Geekguy123")
```

Since you got to set many properties, you can do the following.

```
string[] properties = new string[]{"FirstName","LastName"};

foreach(var property in properties){        
    object value = userToUpdateWith.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(userToUpdateWith, null); 
    userToUpdate.GetProperty(property).SetValue(userToUpdate, value, null);       

c2.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are dozens of properties for this entity that I don't want to update manually

Comment: Then use reflection. Create an array of property names you are interested and then loop through them and through reflection update.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - the pass-through SQL that you can use.

If the table name is *really* Database1, then replace `Table1`, `Table2` accordingly.

```
UPDATE t1
  SET t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName
  FROM Database1.dbo.Table1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.Table2 AS t2
  ON t1.User = t2.User
```

And the passthrough would be like this:

```
using (var context = new YourDataContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlString);
}
```

Comment: He has the tables in different databases.

Comment: Same server? Then just needs to update the passthrough a slight bit more. Assuming the databases are on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there were actually a couple hundred properties. I ended up deleting and re-adding the entity with the new values.